# Site Header not showing in other pages except Homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, adminhtml, header

My site Header is not showing in other pages except the Homepage

My `Header.phtml` Code -

```
(AFL 3.0)
 */
/**
 * @var Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header $this
 */
?>
<div class="header-container">
<div class="header">
    <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
    <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
    <?php else:?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
    <?php endif?>
    <div class="quick-access">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
        <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

**1Column Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        <div class="main-container col1-layout">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                <div class="col-main">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_cookie_notice') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Assuming your homepage as 1column, can you share the code inside 1column.phtml. Also, check in page.xml and local.xml files if there is any condition to remove header from non-Homepages.

Comment: @Prateek - I have added the code for 1column.phtml . I did check my page.xml file (Nothing Specific) and was not able to find local.xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php // if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
<h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
<?php /*else:?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
<?php endif */?>
```

Replace above code in your Header.phtml file. This removes the condition to get the same header in all the pages.

Comment: This is not valid solution

Comment: @Abdul: this the shortest solution for above question.

Comment: I want my header to show on all pages. Is this the best solution?

Comment: @Karan You can try it, may be for you, it could be the best one.

Comment: @MuhammadFayyaz-Ud-DinKhattak - It didn't help. I still cannot see my header in other pages

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good the header should be displayed in all the pages according to the native behavior of Magento, so the issue probably comes from some **xml** you may have to change some tag that make the display is restricted only to the homepage or some extension elsewhere !

In the solution that I give you, I recreate the **header** block again.

Go to : `app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/layout/local.xml` then add this block between `<default>...here...</default>` like this:

```
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
            <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Header</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="page/html_welcome" name="welcome" as="welcome"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

you got it in a template page :

- `1column.phtml`
- `2columns-right.phtml`
- `2columns-left.phtml`
- `3columns.phtml`

like this : `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>`

Besides verifies that you have well `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>` in the templates above. The path : `app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/template/page`